# How to keep the querystring during navigation in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to keep the query string while navigating:

`http://localhost/#/test/page1?param=123`

My navigation links are as follows:

`<a ng-href="test/page2>`

When I click the link, the url changes to: `http://localhost/#/test/page2` and the query string is removed.

Question: how can I keep the query?

Comment: What's the problem to use `<a ng-href="test/page1?param=123">`?

Comment: I get the query from user input, I do not define the query myself. Thus I have to preserve it,.

Comment: You can use `$locationChangeStart` callback and add querystring to URL

Comment: Is it must to keep query string in url? instead use a service to keep it in ngcookie and retrive back on next page

Comment: It's a must to keep the url for user feedback.

Comment: @Tushar could you add an example on `$locationChangeStart`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to not use ng-href you can do this very cleanly and simply using $location.path() like this:

In your controller declare a function that ultimately does this:

```
$scope.sendToNewPlace = function (path) {
    $location.path(path);
}
```

(don't forget to inject $location into your controller (or where-ever you ultimately put the $location.path() call).

Then change your links to use ng-click like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="sendToNewPlace('test/page2');">page2, passing querystring</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
//next: holds the new Url
//current: holds the old Url
});
```

For more Reference :
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: So and how can I change the target url? I tried the following, which changes the `next` variable, but the browser url is *not* changed! `next = next + "?" + current.split('?')[1]`

Comment: function(string1) { string1 = string1 + "anything"} will never change 'string1' )